# Scala Enumeration Val get value of

Tags: scala, playframework, enums, playframework-2.0

In play application I'm using "activate-framework". Enumerations I have to declare this way:

```
object State extends Enumeration {
case class State(value: Int) extends Val(value)
   val OPEN = State(0)
   val CLOSED = State(1)
}
```

Source: http://activate-framework.org/documentation/entity/

How can I get State from Int something like:

```
State.valueOf(1) <==== ??
```

In model I have a field state:

```
import model.State.State
case class Task(var name:String, var state:State)
```

it is State.State case class, how Can I convert Int to State.State class?
When I do State(1) I receive State.Value not State.State class.

Comment: But when I'm trying to assign to field var state:State.State = State(1) I receive: "error: type mismatch;
 found   : State.Value
 required: State.State"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to get value by name you have to declare enum using string constructor:

```
case class State(value: String) extends Val(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> State(1)
res0: State.Value = CLOSED
```

Comment: but how can I cast it to State.State not to State.Value, I have a field var state:State

Comment: Try to explain what you're doing or your post will be automatically flagged as low quality.

Comment: I'm trying to something like this: var state:State.State = State(1), because in model I have a class (State.State) not object (State)